# Randomized Pumpkin Patch

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, random

I was walking through a pumpkin patch the other day for a birthday party, and noticed the pumpkin vines making a nifty pattern, with whirls, loops, and offshoots. We're going to simulate that here with some ASCII art.

```
          (())
            \
   p--q      p-----q
  /    \    /       \
(())    b--d       (())
```

#### Vine Construction Rules

- There is only one main vine, composed solely of `\ / - p q b d` characters.
- The vine only travels from left to right across the screen. In other words, suppose you were an ant starting at the left-most vine character. As you progress to the next adjacent character on the main vine, you *must* move one column to the right - never to the left.
- When the vine changes direction, one of the `p q b d` characters are required to simulate a loop. The `p` joins vines traveling northeast to east, the `q` for east to southeast, the `b` from southeast to east, and the `d` from east to northeast. Note that the "loop" of the letter connects to the horizontal vine, and the "stem" of the letter connects to the diagonal.
- The beginning of the vine must be one of `p` or `b` (your choice, doesn't have to be random), and starts horizontally. The end of the vine must be one of `q` or `d` (your choice, doesn't have to be random), and must end horizontally.
- Note that loops can be placed immediately adjacent to other loops (e.g., `pd` is a valid substring of the vine), but that may make it more difficult to place the pumpkins later. You may want to always have one of `- / \` immediately after a loop (as I did in my examples), but it's not required.

#### Pumpkin Rules

- The pumpkins are composed solely of `(())` (this exact string).
- From the main vine, the pumpkins are attached by offshoots. These offshoots can only be attached to the `p q b d` loops, are precisely one `\` or `/` in length, and attach to the pumpkin so the "end" of the offshoot is in the middle.
- They can connect above or below the main vine.
- The offshoots can connect going to the "left."
- Only one pumpkin can attach per offshoot, and only one offshoot per loop.

#### Randomness

- When traveling horizontally, the vine has a 50% chance of continuing horizontally, a 25% chance of turning northeast, and a 25% chance of turning southeast.
- When traveling diagonally, the vine has a 90% chance of turning horizontal and a 10% chance of continuing diagonally.
- There must be sufficient turns to support the input number of pumpkins, though more turns are allowed.
- Once the vine is constructed, pumpkins can be randomly placed at any corner not already occupied by a pumpkin.
- Pumpkins cannot overlap the vine or other pumpkins.

#### The Challenge

Given an input number, output a randomized pumpkin patch following the above rules. Executing the code multiple times with the same input should yield different results. All possible pumpkin patches for a given input number should have some (not necessarily equal) non-zero chance of occurring.

#### Input

A single integer `n` representing the number of pumpkins in the patch, in [any convenient format](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/42963). For brevity of code, you can assume the input is `0 < n < 256`.

#### Output

The resulting pumpkin patch, either printed/displayed to the screen or returned as a string/string-array/etc.

#### Rules

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so all the usual rules for golfing apply, and the shortest code (in bytes) wins.
- Use our [standard definition](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1325/42963) of "Random."
- Either a full program or function are acceptable.
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/42963) are forbidden.
- Leading and trailing whitespace / newlines are all completely optional.

#### Examples

For input `n = 3`, here are some VALID examples of a pumpkin patch following the above rules (separated by blank newlines).

```
          (())
            \
   p--q      p-----q
  /    \    /       \
(())    b--d       (())

(()) (())
  \   /
   b-q (())
      \ /
       b-q

p-----------------------q (())
                       / \ /
                     (()) b-q
                           /
                         (())
```

Here are some INVALID examples for input `n = 3`, with explanations `#`.

```
    (()) (())
     /    /
p---q----q
 \
(())
# The vine continued horizontally after a loop was placed.

(()(())
  \ /
   p---q
        \
       (())
# The pumpkins are both overlapping and sprouting from the same loop.

p----------------q
 \      \         \
(())   (())      (())
# The pumpkin is attached to the middle of the vine, not at a loop.
```

Comment: And now design a 2D language using this as the syntax. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Python 2, 819 bytes

Takes `n` as input

Always places pumkpins on the 'outside' of corners (randomly left/right)

While the vine is constructed, pumpkins are added, and when enough pumpkins are there, the vine stops.

```python
r=lambda:__import__('random').random()
s=1
v=[s]*4
U=[-9]
D=[-9]
i=input()
while len(U)+len(D)<i+2:s=[[0,1][r()<.9],[[0,2][r()<.5],1][r()<.5],[2,1][r()<.9]][s];exec['',[['','U+=[len(v)]'][U[-1]<len(v)-7],'',['','D+=[len(v)]'][D[-1]<len(v)-7]][v[-1]-s+1]][r()<.8];v+=[s]*[1,2][v[-1]!=s]
v+=[1]*5
m=M=s=0
for i in v:s+=i-1;m=[m,s][m>s];M=[M,s][M<s]
R=[[' ']*(M-m+5)for x in v]
m=-m+2
R[2][m]='p'
for x in range(3,len(v)-3):X=v[x-1];R[x][m]='/d p-b q\\'[v[x]*3+X];m+=v[x]-1
R[-3][m]='q'
M=[len(a)-len(a.lstrip())for a in map(''.join,R)]
R=map(list,zip(*R))
B,L,a='-/U'
K="\\"*4
W="""exec("for p in "+a+"[1:]:x=M[p];b=r()<.5;exec('R[x"+B+"1][p'+['+1]=\\""+L+"\\"','-1]=\\""+K+"\\"'][b]);i=p-[0,3][b];l='(';exec('R[x"+B+"2][i]=l;i+=1;'*2+'l=\\")\\";')*2")"""
exec W+";B,a='+D';L,K=K,L;"+W
for x in R:print''.join(map(str,x))
```

#### Examples:

`n=4`

```
                (())   
                 /     
                p---q  
 (())          /       
   \       p--d        
  p-q     /    \       
     \   /    (())     
      b-d              
       \               
      (())
```

`n=20`

```
                            (())                                                                                             
                              \                                                                                              
                            p--q                                                                                             
                           /    \                                                                                            
                          /      b--q                                                                                        
           (())     p----d      /    \                                                                                       
  (())       \     /          (())    b-q (())                                                                               
    \         p---d                      \  \                                                                                
  p--q       /     \                      b--q                                                                               
      \     /     (())                   /    \                        (())                                           (())   
       b---d                           (())    b-q                       \                                             /     
        \                                         \          (())         p-q                                         p---q  
       (())                                        \           \         /   \                                       /       
                                                    b-----------q     p-d     b-q                            (())p--d        
                                                                 \   /       /   \                            / /    \       
                                                                  b-d      (())   b-q   (())  (())   p-q     p-d    (())     
                                                                   /                 \   /      \   /   \   /                
                                                                 (())                 b-q        p-d     b-d                 
                                                                                       \ \      /         \                  
                                                                                      (())b----d         (())                
                                                                                              /                              
                                                                                            (())
```

Comment: Congrats, you win by default! :D